# Group data based on range in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table products in my database. price column has various repeating values. I want to fetch count of products based on range 10-50, 51-100 and so on.

One way I could identify was to execute multiple queries on the database with different where clauses.

I was wondering if it could be done in one query itself.

what I tried was

```
$q = "SELECT count(*) FROM products WHERE price>10 AND price<50"
$q1 = "SELECT count(*) FROM products WHERE price>50 AND price<100"
```

Now this gives me the count of individual ranges, but I have to manually write queries for all the ranges.

Comment: could you please provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_name, 
       count(case when price between 10 and 50 then 1 else null end) as `10-50 count`,
       count(case when price between 51 and 100 then 1 else null end) as `51-100 count`
from products
group by product_name
```